# matlab2tikz one label entry missing

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

when I use the command matlab2tikz, I have one label missing. I have a specific procedure to make this figure because I want only some marker in Matlab. To do that for one plot I make this following procedure in three steps: 
First, I plot the plot with only the line without a label. Second I plot only the marker  without label.  Finally, I plot one point with line and marker for the legend.
Now for better quality I want to convert in tikz, but it's strange when I convert one label missing only when I specify logscale...
You can find the figure in .fig and the results in pdf in the following link:
[https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gnxwmqjkico3h8z/AACuqPBQxY0pJaU3s3AL-Obga?dl=0][1]

Answer (score 2):

I have solve my problem, the coordinate of the only point used for the legend entry are not in the domain, so matlab2tikz decide to discard the legend entry... 
to solve the problem I have change in tikz the coordinate to one point appear in the domain. 
for example
0.512478    7.16330877589454\